# Error during raising review request in ReviewBoard

Tags: review-board

I have installed reviewboard. I added local GIT repository to it. During creation of review requests, the repository is available to be selected. But, when I am selecting a file from the repository and trying to add it as a Diff it says 'The selected file does not appear to be a diff.'. Please let me know if anyone has any answer for the question. Thanks....

Answer (score 1):

```
git diff <filename1> ><filename2>.diff
```

This can be used for generating the diff file.

Answer (score 0):

```
Some helpful tips for reviewboard are:

Log Settings:
Check/Tick - Enable logging
Log directory: /var/www/reviewboard
Log Level: Debug

Review board git configuration steps::
$ git config --global user.name "Chalpat Rauth"
$ git config --global user.email chalpat.rauth@ap.sony.com
You can veryify the entries in vim ~/.gitconfig
$ ssh-keygen -t rsa
copy the public key ./root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to gitlab as a new key 
chmod 700 -R /root/.ssh/
git clone git@gitlab.csx.sony.co.jp:testtest.git
During configuration in ReviewBoard:
Hosting service: None - Custom Repository
Repository Type: Git
Path: /var/www/reviewboard/code/testtest/.git
Note the below:
In path: /var/www/reviewboard/code/testtest/helloworld/src/test/java/com/sony/csx
git add <file_name>
git commit -m "This is second commit"
git push
git diff HEAD >DiffForReview

LDAP Settings::
Check/Tick - Allow anonymous read-only access
Authentication Method: LDAP
LDAP Server: ldap://ldap.csx.sony.co.jp
LDAP Base DN: dc=csx,dc=sony,dc=co,dc=jp
Surname Attribute: csxUsername1
Full Name Attribute: csxUsernameF
E-Mail LDAP Attribute: mail
User Mask: uid=%s
```